# FilesMatch to specific route but doesn't match to another (.htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I try to deny access to routes matching with `wp-json/*` except the route `wp-json/contact-form-7/*` in my .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ^wp-json((?!\/contact-form-7).)*$>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This does not work, do you know why ?

I also try this

```
<FilesMatch ^wp-json(?!/contact-form-7)>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Did you try with double quote before and after the regex ? And can you detail what is not working ? No route are bloqued ? Or all the `wp-json.*` are bloqued ?

Comment: The `^` means it  is the begining of the string, you should maybe remove it

Comment: All wp-json are bloqued.

Comment: I try with quote and without ^ but no changes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be directory match and you need to enclose the file pattern in quotes and that should do the trick!

```
<DirectoryMatch "^wp-json(?!/contact-form-7)">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: This does'nt work, the solution is maybe to try an other way to do what i want to do ?